# Save buffer before opening new file

Tags: buffers, autocmd

When I'm in a modified buffer and try to open a file using `:e otherFile` I get

> E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)

Since this happens fairly often, I'd like to automatically save the current file before opening the new one.

That's why I added this to my `vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufLeave * silent! wall
```

But this autocommand doesn't help when using `:e otherFile`.

---

Using Neovim v0.4.3

Comment: Why not use `:h 'hidden'` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dedowsdi! Can you describe the difference between `:set hidden` and `:set autowriteall` in an answer?

Comment: Sorry, don't have time for that. You can read `:h 'hidden'` and `:h 'autowriteall'`, then try both (make sure only one of them is set), you should see the difference immediately, won't cost more 15 mins.

Comment: I read the docs and tried both `hidden` and `autowriteall` alternatingly but couldn't tell the difference in behavior. In both cases the buffer that I was leaving was saved.

Comment: You must make sure only one of them is on. `'hidden'` won't work if `'autowrite'` or `'autowriteall'` is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is

```
set hidden
```

This allows a buffer to be made « hidden », i.e., not physically shown in a window, while still unsaved.

Without `'hidden'` on, vim’s default behavior is to not allow closing a modified buffer without being forced (via `!`s on commands). `'hidden'` allows a third state between open and closed.

Do note that `'confirm'` may be useful here; I believe it instructs vim to confirm, when you quit, the save/don’t save state of any modified buffers.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to

`:set autowriteall`

This will save the file before switching to another and also save it before quitting Vim. So every time you type commands like `:bn`, short form for `:bnext`, the buffer will be saved automatically and the buffer changed, in this case for the next one in a circular manner.

Gleaned from `:help autowrite` and `:help autowriteall`:

> Write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each
> next, :rewind, :last, :first, :previous, :stop, :suspend, :tag, :!,
> make, CTRL-] and CTRL-^ command; and when a :buffer, CTRL-O, CTRL-I
> command takes you to a new file. Also write when using :edit, :enew,
> :quit, :qall, :exit, :xit, :recover and closing the Vim window.